# Microsoft Word: Select and GoTo InlineShape

Tags: vba, ms-word

A macro in my Word document goes through all the graphs (inlineshapes) and updates links and values. At the moment the document freezes for the whole process behind a "Please wait" form dialog. Ideally I'd have the code move throughout the document to show the user that stuff is actually happening.

How can I select and GoTo the current inlineshape within my loop below?

```
Private Sub UpdateFields()

PleaseWait.bar.Width = 0
PleaseWait.Show

' This routine sets the new path for external links, pointing them to the current folder.
Dim Rng As Range, Fld As Field, Shp As Shape, iShp As InlineShape, i As Long

Dim no_of_steps As Integer
Dim single_step_width As Integer
no_of_steps = 0

With ThisDocument
  
    ' Create progress bar
    ' a) Count total number of steps
    For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
        For Each iShp In Rng.InlineShapes
            no_of_steps = no_of_steps + 1
        Next iShp
    Next Rng

    ' b) Divide full width of progress frame by number of steps
    single_step_width = PleaseWait.frame.Width \ no_of_steps


    ' Go through all story ranges in the document.
    For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
        ' Go through the inlineshapes in the story range.
        For Each iShp In Rng.InlineShapes
        
            With iShp
                ' Skip over inlineshapes that don't have links to external files.
                If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
                    With .LinkFormat
                        ' Skip links already set to current folder
                        If Not .SourceFullName = ThisDocument.Path & "\datagrunnlag.xlsm" Then
                            
                            ' Replace the link to the external file
                            .SourceFullName = ThisDocument.Path & "\datagrunnlag.xlsm"
                            On Error Resume Next
                            .AutoUpdate = False
                            .Update
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        End If
                        
                    End With
                End If
                
                ' Update progress bar with completed step
                PleaseWait.bar.Width = PleaseWait.bar.Width + single_step_width
                DoEvents
                
                End With
        Next iShp
    Next Rng

End With
End Sub
```

Edit 05.12.2020: added all code within the sub. ScreenUpdating = False and True are being set by separate subs for MacroEntry and MacroExit.

Comment: That would be a really bad idea. Using the `Selection` object will slow the operation down even more. You already appear to have a progress indicator, so you are already informing the user that things are happening.

Comment: Thanks. Could something else than Selection/GoTo be better, but achieve the same effect, or would my intention here be a bad idea regardless? Please feel free to place your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The problem should be in the call of `PleaseWait.bar`. Please add that code to your question.

Comment: Added code for thw whole sub, showing how I create and update my progress bar. The progress bar window itself is a user form with a simple frame and a green bar inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a really bad idea. Using the Selection object will just slow the operation down even more, and leave the user cursing you.

As you already appear to have a progress indicator, you are doing all that you can to keep the user informed.

Anything that involves scrolling the document makes your code run more slowly, so the best you can do is ensure your code completes in as short a time as possible. This includes avoiding use of the `Selection` object and turning off `ScreenUpdating`.